# Mask the display of number except last four. Angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I want to mask the display of Social Security number except the last four digits but retain the value in the field.

I tried ui-mask but it didn't help.

Any suggestion please.

Comment: make a custom filter that does that.

Comment: "_I tried ui-mask_" Show us that attempt and explain what specifically did not work about it.

Comment: Is not save to have the real value in the field. You could have two fields, one hidden and the masked one to display, so you get the last digits and fill out the first part with "X" or any character you want to use...

Answer (score 1):

Create a custom filter like

```
app.filter('mask',function(){
      return function(input){
           var last=input.substring(input.length-4,input.length);
           var first=input.substring(0,input.length-4);
              first=first.replace(/[a-zA-Z0-9]/g,'X');
            var res=first+last;
            return res;
      }
});
```